# Can I have multiple ssl certs for a single domain?

Tags: ssl-certificate

For a single domain, can I have two different ssl certs from two different CAs, each cert has its own expiration date, and use them on different servers? Does the earlier cert automatically expire?

Thanks

Comment: Intrigued as to what your use case is... could you elaborate?

Comment: I need to use different cdn services in different countries, one of them does not support uploading ssl certs, it can only sign new cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this would be fine. As far as the client is concerned changing certificates and IP addresses for domains is acceptable provided both certs have valid chains to trusted CA's.